# MySQL Connector Python 3.6

Tags: mysql, pip, python-3.6, connector

I'm using Python 3.6 on Windows 10 and trying to connect with MySQL.

I've successfully installed connectors with **pip3 install mysql-connector** and **mysql-connector-python**, but in my Python code, the line **import mysql.connector** still fails, giving me a ModuleNotFoundError.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you run your script with the same Python that was used for `pip3`? Any chance your script is called `mysql.py`?

Answer (score 0):

First, Check have you install it.

Follow if you are stuck.

1. Open IDLE python. CTRL+N and CTRL+O and select Scripts Folder

"It should open the explorer where you have to install python like C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\scripts"

2. CTRL+L and CTRL+C
3. Open CMD and CTRL+V

"cd C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\scripts"
[image]

That's it. Hope it will solve your problem